# Copy a range of cells in a column many times. Excel - Calc

Tags: excel, database, calc

I need a formula to copy a range of cells into x-times. I have a huge database with 200 000 rows. In my column D I want to copy the first 100 cells, with some values I already assigned to them, 2000 times in the same column. I am working with Calc from LibreOffice.

> Row(D1-D100) = [1,2,3....100]
>
> Row(D101-D200) = [1,2,3....100]
>
> Row(...-...) = ...
>
> Row(D199900-D200000) = [1,2,3....100]

I'd rather cell formulas than Excel code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the row() function for the first 100 and then do some maths for the following ones.

See the result in cell B1 with the function shown in C1

[image]